# Why is SQL integral Numeric column mapped as System.Decimal in a C# DataSet?

Tags: c#, sql-server, types, dataset, dataadapter

Why is SQL integral numeric column (for example `NUMERIC(3,0)`) generated in C# (in DataSet
as column type or in DataAdapter as parameter type) as type `Decimal`?

`NUMERIC(3,0)` can store integral values in range of -999 to 999. I think it should be in C# generated as type `int` or another integral one.

I think, this behavior is .NET or Visual Studio serious bug. How should I solve it, if I don't want rewrite generated code and I don't want to convert everywhere I use it between int and decimal? Thank you.

Comment: What do you think is different in SQL Server between `NUMERIC` and `DECIMAL`? If you think this is a bug, why don't you report it at [http://connect.microsoft.com/](http://connect.microsoft.com/)?

Comment: @pst no, in SQL Server `NUMERIC` and `DECIMAL` are absolutely 100% interchangeable. I think you are thinking about `DECIMAL` vs. `FLOAT` or `REAL` perhaps.

Comment: @AaronBertrand No, I was thinking about NUMERIC(38) vs System.Decimal. I *thought* the latter might lose at the fringe ...

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: NUMERIC(X, 0) is integral, and definitely no decimal type.

Comment: Yes the mapping between .Net types and SQL Server types is not completely on par.

Comment: @PavelHodek I'm not sure what you mean. It is still a decimal type even if you happen to have specified that there are no decimal places. Perhaps you can elaborate on what actual problem you are trying to solve? I think Brad has some good clues, but your perspective would likely be at least as accurate.

Comment: @Aaron: Maybe it is still decimal type, but is accepting integral values only - for my point of view it is useful to have it in application as System.Int32.

Comment: Ok. Like I said, if you think it's a bug, report it as a bug. I think you're going to have a hard time convincing anyone here of that, and even if you do, what do you expect StackOverflow users to do about it?

Comment: @Aaron: I'm looking for a solution for not to have to edit generated code or not to make conversions - if I have to use the value in application as `System.Int32`. I know the use of this database type definition is fail, but it is legacy code. Maybe it's not a bug, but it is strange and uncomfortable behavior of Visual Studio code generator. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're dealing with apples and oranges in this case: the database has a floating point field and your program is expecting an integer. One of those is going to have to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is why MSSQL `NUMERIC` is converted to C# `Decimal` and the answer is because `NUMERIC` is still a floating point value even though you specify that it has no decimal places like `NUMERIC[3,0]`.

It would not make sense if `NUMERIC` where converted into C# into different types depending on whether or not you indicated it has any decimal points or not.

I assume you are using `NUMERIC[3,0]` to save space in the database, but according to the docs, it [uses 5 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746). A SQL `INT`, on the other hand, [only uses 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).  And, even better, a `SMALLINT` [uses only 2 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).

Unfortunately, you're either going to have to convert your database to use `SMALLINTs` instead of `NUMERIC` or you're going to have to convert in your C#.

It would be nice if you had only one entity that retrieved data from your database and then you could keep your conversions to a minimum and localized to a single location.

Comment: And a SMALLINT, which can accommodate every value a NUMERIC(3,0) can, only takes 2 bytes.

Comment: I'm working with legacy code. Some developers set natural integral values as NUMERIC(3, 0) for validating maximum value up to 999. I think it should be INT or so. In C# it is generated as System.Decimal, but database is in this column accepting of course integer values only. I have to made some conversion when I work with value - it should be treated in application as integer.

Comment: Using the wrong type in the database is due to previous developers are users of the Oracle database, from where they brought the "bad" habits to SQL Server.

Comment: I would rather refactor the database than try to trick C# into think a decimal isn't a decimal.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, good point on the `smallint`; I'll edit my answer. I also agree that refactoring the database would be the way to go if possible.